# ArrayList<HeavyOjbect> clone()

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, clone

I've got a question about the clone() method for an ArrayList in Java.

```
ArrayList<HeavyOjbect> original = new ArrayList<HeavyOjbect>();
original.add(new HeavyOjbect(0));
original.add(new HeavyOjbect(1));
original.add(new HeavyOjbect(2));
ArrayList<Integer> copy = original;
copy.remove(0);
```

original -> [HeavyOjbect1, HeavyOjbect2]

copy ->  [HeavyOjbect1, HeavyOjbect2]

Now using the clone() method

```
ArrayList<HeavyOjbect> original = new ArrayList<HeavyOjbect>();
original.add(new HeavyOjbect(0));
original.add(new HeavyOjbect(1));
original.add(new HeavyOjbect(2));
ArrayList<Integer> copy = (ArrayList<HeavyOjbect>) original.clone();
copy.remove(0);
```

original -> [HeavyOjbect0, HeavyOjbect1, HeavyOjbect2]

copy ->  [HeavyOjbect1, HeavyOjbect2]

right ?

But I can't figure out what clone does. Does it clone every HeavyObject? 
I mean if a clone 1000 times my ArrayList, does the memory explode ?

**Edit :
So with clone**

```
new HeavyOjbect(0) -> @10
new HeavyOjbect(1) -> @20
new HeavyOjbect(1) -> @30

original(ref1 to @10, ref1 to @20, ref1 to @30)
copy(ref2 to @10, ref2 to @20, ref2 to @30)
```

right ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone()

> public Object clone()
>   Returns a shallow copy of this ArrayList instance. (The elements themselves are not copied.)

Only the *references* to your `HeavyObject`s are copied; each cloned `ArrayList` will contain references to the exact same objects. No new `HeavyObject`s will be created.

**Edit to add:** This is the difference between a "shallow" and a "deep" copy. If it were a deep copy then a copy of each `HeavyObject` would also be made, and as you say ... your memory  would explode.

Answer (score 1):

clone() method is used to create a copy of an object of a class which implements Cloneable interface. By default it does field-by-field copy as the Object class doesn't have any idea in advance about the members of the particular class whose objects call this method. So, if the class has only primitive data type members then a completely new copy of the object will be created and the reference to the new object copy will be returned. But, if the class contains members of any class type then only the object references to those members are copied and hence the member references in both the original object as well as the cloned object refer to the same object.
So it will not does any memory explode.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
ArrayList<Integer> copy = original;
```

You are reffering `copy` refference also points to `original` object.

If you modify object through `copy` refference it will change on `original` object also.

**Clone:**

clone() method will give another copy of same object , so if you cahnge in `copy` object it will reflect in `original` object.